# Compile standalone ext4 userspace program

Tags: c, ext4

I'm looking forward to write a standalone userspace program which makes use of some of the functions defined in the ext4 kernel module, e.g.:

```c
struct ext4_group_desc * ext4_get_group_desc(struct super_block * sb,
                            ext4_group_t block_group,
                            struct buffer_head ** bh);
```

I provided this specific function name as example, but I shall be able to call any of the ext4 module's functions.

Questions:

1. What headers do I need in order to compile? Are there ext4 libraries meant for userspace?
2. Assuming that I had an ext4 filesystem on `/dev/sda5` and that I wanted to work with block group number 23, how to correctly initialize the variables to be passed to `ext4_get_group_desc`? How to get the superblock in particular?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem. Why do you ask?

Comment: There is a userspace library `libext2fs`, distributed along with the e2fsprogs utilities (despite the name it also supports ext3 and ext4).  See http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. In general, kernel code can only be directly called by other kernel code (the main exception being syscalls). That function doesn't fall under any of the exceptions.